# Pass PHP associative array cursor as function parameter

Tags: php, arrays, cursor

I'm trying to figure out how to pass an array cursor (i.e. an arbitrary location in an array) as a function parameter. Assume I've got the following array:

```
$recipe = array("ingredient1"=>array(
                    "type"=>"cheddar cheese",
                    "quantity"=>"1 cup",
                    "format"=>"shredded"
                ),
                "ingredient2"=>array(
                     "type"=>"wheat bread",
                      "quantity"=>"2 slices"
                 )
          );
```

Assume additionally that I've got a function `thingee(&$recipe)` that (obviously) accepts `$recipe` as a parameter by reference.

Question:  How can I pass `thingee()` a location within `$recipe`, i.e. `$recipe["ingredient1"]["quantity"]`, `$recipe["ingredient2"]["type"]`, etc.

Comment: try $arg = &$recipe["ingredient1"];  thingee($arg);

Comment: if `thingee` accepts recipe - you cannot pas it ingredient quantity or type, you need to pass whole `$recipe`

Comment: You guys both missed the point - I already knew how to pass the array by reference.  My interest was in whether you could somehow pass the array cursor as an additional parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass it as you indicate:

```
function thingee(&$recipe) {
    $recipe = "gouda";
}

$recipe = array("ingredient1"=>array("type"=>"cheddar cheese"));
thingee($recipe["ingredient1"]["type"]);
echo $recipe["ingredient1"]["type"]; // outputs: gouda
```

However, you cannot expect in the function *thingee* to be able to move to another element in the global *$recipe* array. It just receives that one element without "parent" or "sybling" context.

Comment: Ah, so since I'm passing by reference I can essentially pass the array node as a location?  I'll go try something and check back in a second.

Comment: Yes, I tried it with several versions of PHP (>= 5.3) and it seems to work in all of them.

Comment: You've definitely answered my original question; it's even possible to append elements to the passed reference (i.e. $recipe["newthing"]="stuff"), and it will appear appropriately as part of $recipe in the calling context.  Sadly, the point you make about not being able to move to another element is sadly correct.

Comment: For that last (sad) issue, you could look into [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php). The idea would be that you first put the iterator to the desired point (e.g. by using the `next` method) and then pass that to your function, which could then do another `next` if it wanted to. Also I think the changes to the array will be in the original array. Anyway, lot's of possibilities there.

Comment: Actually, I've worked up a solution based on using an array of key names to construct an eval() statement to point to the desired spot in the array.  It's probably sacrilegious, and may create other problems if I try to scale it up, but it seems to be working for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

example as solution:

```
function a(&$a){ $a=$a.'#'; }
$array = array("foo" => "bar");
$t = &$array["foo"];            
a($t);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how and why it solves the problem and doesn’t introduce others.